# Python string matching, error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Tags: python, regex, string, matching

I have a column called `cc_flags' in a Python astropy table. It looks like::

### cc_flags

```
0000
ddOO
0000
hHOO
0000
DD00
hHOO
hHPO
P000
00h0
...
0000
```

I'd like to pull out every row with the last character of the four if it is a '0'., i.e a '***0' or a '???0' matcher.

I'm getting an

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

with

```
import re
regex = r"???0"
re.findall(regex,data['cc_flags'])
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Do you have to use regex?

Comment: You are using wildcard-matching instead of regular expressions. Consider using [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) or changing your regex to `...0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not limited to regex or regex like, this is simple:

```
has_zeros = [line for line in data['cc_flags'] if line[-1] == '0']
```

This list comprehension will extract out each element from `data['cc_flags']` into a variable named line, and return a resulting list that is only comprised of the last character of line being a 0.

(Obviously, if you need your if statement to be more specific, you can add whatever else you need into the filter condition.)

Comment: You could also use [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Absolutely, though I would expect line[-1] to be more efficient than line.endswith() .

Comment: Sure, it probably is, but so is array access.  At least on my system, [-1] is much more efficient for this case:

`$ python -m timeit 'if "1230"[-1] == "0": pass'`
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0177 usec per loop
`$ python -m timeit 'if "1230".endswith("0"): pass'`
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0709 usec per loop

But we're getting lost in the weeds.  I simply wanted to present a non-regex solution.  Either [-1] or .endswith can work, depending on your needs.  (Both are much more efficient than regex.  :-) )

Comment: I kinda wanted the regex solution for general learning, but this does work and does ultimately do what I want!! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`?` does not mean "any character" in regex. Swap your `?`s for `.`s

Comment: regex = "...0"                                                      re.findall(regex,data['cc_flags'])                                                               then gives me a "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"

Comment: @npross `regex = rb'...0'`?

Comment: @npross The the astropy data structure you're using is the "bytes-like object". As Mr Lettuce mentions, adding the `b` flag to your regex will allow it to match.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to use `.` instead of `?`. Another way is to use `{}` to specify how many matches.

For example, try this:

```
import re
regex = r".{3}0"
re.findall(regex,data['cc_flags'])
```

- `.` means match any character (except for line terminators)
- `{3}` means match exactly 3 times

Comment: (Also) gives me a  TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: @npross `regex = rb'.{3}0'`?

Comment: This doesn't crash, but gives me::                                  
[b'\x00\x00\x000',
 b'\x00\x00\x000',
 b'\x00\x00\x000',
 b'\x00\x00\x000',

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with regex not escaping the special characters in your search term. To get this to work, simply change your statement to the following:

```py
import re
regex = re.escape("???0")
re.findall(regex,data['cc_flags'])
```

`data['cc_flags']` should be a string, not a list.